# Implementing nested HTTP-Requests in Android using Retrofit2 and RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

Within my Activity I am firing an HTTP Request with `Retrofit2`. On success I receive an array of elements. On every element I fire a second request which again responses with an array of elements on success. I need an event to trigger as soon as all nested requests are finished. How can I achieve that without counting the successes of every nested request and comparing it to the size of the first array? Here is my `Activity`:

```
public class ABCActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "StackoverflowActivity";

    private Disposable mDmRequestSubscription;
    private StopRequestApiInteractor mStopRequestInteractor;
    private DmRequestApi mDmRequestApiInteractor;

    private Position mPosition;

    private List<ItdOdvAssignedStop> mStopsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<List<ItdDeparture>> mAllDepartures;
    private List<Place> mStopsInRange = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Place> stopsInRange;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestStops();
    }

    public void requestStops() {
        mStopRequestInteractor
                .getStopFinderRespond(mPosition)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(s -> Observable.just(s.getStopFinder().getItdOdvAssignedStops()))
                .subscribe(this::onSuccess, this::onError);
    }

    private void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }

    private void onSuccess(ItdOdvAssignedStop[] response) {
        mStopsList.clear();
        mStopsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(response));

        for (ItdOdvAssignedStop stop : mStopsList) {
            mDmRequestSubscription = mDmRequestApiInteractor
                    .getStopDmRespond(stop.getStopID())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(this::onDmRequestSuccess, this::onDmRequestError);
        }
    }

    private void onDmRequestError(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "DM Request failed");
    }

    private void onDmRequestSuccess(ResponseBody entry) {
        Log.d(TAG, "DM Request success");
        mStopsInRange = getStopsInRange();
        update();
    }

    public List<Place> getStopsInRange() {
        //Some things done here...
        return stopsInRange;
    }

    private void update() {
        //Shall be called only once as soon as all onDmRequestSuccess() were fired
    }
}
```

My Activity is not runnable outside of my project. I just want a clean solution to trigger `update()` only once as soon as all requests are responded. And not every time a nested request is responded.

How can I implement that using `onNext()`, `onCompleted()` and `onError()` methods of `Subscriber`? So how to transform my code into something like the following?

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onNext("Test");
        subscriber.onError(null);
    }
}).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.println("onCompleted");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("onError");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                System.out.println("onNext");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using 2 flatMaps. The trigger you are looking for is the onComplete call itself, as all streams will either terminate normally or with an exception which will be propagated into onError method.

Conceptually, you are looking for something like this:

```
getMainRequest()
    .flatMap(itemList -> Observable.from(itemList))
    .flatMap(item -> secondRequest(item))
    .subscribe(result -> {

    }, error -> {
        // some stream encountered an error
    }, () -> {
        // all requests have finished
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Does you code take into account that there is a `for` loop within the first `onSucess()` method?

Comment: that is handled by the first flatMap, which will take the resulting list and iterate through it as separate items.. second flatMap will map that item to a second request